# nvd3.js stackedAreaChart chart transitions. Like on nvd3.org

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

So my question is pretty simple. 
How to achieve the same smoothness as on [nvd3.org](http://nvd3.org) for `stackedAreaChart`.
When you click on it, it changes its states slowly and smoothly.
In my project if I use latest nv.d3.js from https://github.com/novus/nvd3 I have no smoothness. If I replace it with nv.d3.js from nvd3.org everything works fine.

Any suggestions? Maybe it can be somehow achieved through d3.js API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the transitions were very recently disabled for `stackedAreaCharts` in the repository, as pointed out in this issue: https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/45

This change has not made it to the version hosted on nvd3.org yet. This explains why the transitions work on using the version hosted there while they don't work in the latest build from Github.

Comment: Is there a way we can enable the transitions in the new nvd3 version?

Comment: Just call `.transition()` on the `selection` before calling `nvd3` objects using `.call` on them.

Comment: I tried your suggestion like this: d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data).transition().duration(400).call(chart); but it is still showing the same behavior. Any guesses?

Comment: In btw. I am using stackedAreaChart .. so i was asking if there is a way to enable transition in this particular charting technique?

Comment: That should do it and that is what is suggested on their examples page: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html which has some transitions during interactions. Those are not the transitions you are looking for? :)

Comment: You're basically correct. They disabled transitions since some version.
Though I managed to achieve required behavior but only by modifying nvd3 source code.